# Display attached multiple images after attaching and sending mail in PHP MAILER

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to workout a form where all date is emailed to user with attachments(images only) and images are also displayed in browser.

I am able to upload multiple images to folder and send email with attachment. But how to display the images one after other with fixed width only after sending. I am able to  display only first image but not all of them, please suggest

Thanks in advance

```
<?php 

    $msg = '';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;;
    include_once 'PHPMailer.php';
    include_once 'Exception.php';
    include_once 'SMTP.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $inputZip = $_POST['inputZip'];


        $mail = new PHPMailer; //moved here

        if (isset($_FILES['images']['name']) && $_FILES['images']['name'] != '') {
            $destination = "";
            foreach ($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"] as $key => $value) {
                $tmp_name = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
                $name = $destination . basename($_FILES["images"]["name"][$key]);
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $name);
                $mail->addAttachment($name); //attache here
            }
        } else {
            $name = '';
        }



    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = '';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = '';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    $mail->setFrom('@EMAIL', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('@EMAIL', '');     // Add a recipient


        $mail->Subject = 'from Website';
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Body =  '


    ';


        if ($mail->send()) {
             echo 'Message has been sent';
        } else {
            echo 'error';
        }


    }
```

Comment: This is really unclear. Are you talking about displaying the images inside the email? What have you tried? Where's your code?

Comment: It didn't post code, I have corrected it, I don't want to embed in email just show in browser

Comment: In that case this has nothing to do with the email code at all - upload the images, move them into a public folder, and then generate URLs pointing to them which you include in your HTML output.

Comment: I have to show them when its uploaded, right after "Message send"

Comment: Right, so do what I suggested

Comment: How do I generate url pointing to them.?

Comment: `<img src="/path/to/whereever/you/uploaded/them/image.png">`